# Raphael JS fill SVG with image -> scaling?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a path filled with an image `path.attr({'fill': 'url(https://alastaira.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/image13.png)'})` to simulate a background with hatching.
When I zoom the path (via a Raphael js zooming plugin), of course the image scales too and gets blurry.

1. Is it possible to use a .svg image as background? If yes, how can I scale it?
2. Is it possible to disable the scaling of the background image? So when I zoom, the background image doesn't zoom, too?

Comment: I tried using a .svg image as background, but the size/scale was totally wrong...

Comment: I would put a concise testing example up on a jsfiddle, so people can look at the specific problem, with a description of how you want it to be. Its really difficult to know any specific problems without seeing some code.